# Android: write to Bluetooth output fails

Tags: android, bluetooth

My app uses a Bluetooth connection to remotely control a robot, but I can't write to it (send bytes to the robot) as I get a very bizarre fatal error.

Here's my Application class that takes care of the bluetooth connection, I need to put it there because multiple activities use the connection (only one at the time). The code is taken from the BluetoothChat sample.

```
public class BluetoothRemoteControlApp extends Application {
    // . . .

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        // . . .

        public void run() {
            try {
                // blocking function, error is here
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                connectionFailed();
                return;
            }

            synchronized (BluetoothRemoteControlApp.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // start connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        // . . .

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                communicationHandler.obtainMessage(BT_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(String data) {
        byte[] out = data.getBytes();
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        // This is where my app fails (commenting here makes my app run)
        r.write(out);
    }

    // . . .
}
```

Specifically my app fails at `r.write(out);` inside the `write(String data)` function. I'm calling it from another activity, that uses the phones accelerometer, like this:

```
public class AccelerometerControl extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    BluetoothRemoteControlApp appState;

    // . . .

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // . . .

        appState = (BluetoothRemoteControlApp) getApplicationContext();
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // . . .

        // send data to robot
        appState.write("s,"+wheelLeft+","+wheelRight);
    }
}
```

The error log I get goes like this:

```
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644):    at com.bluetooth.BluetoothRemoteControlApp.write(BluetoothRemoteControlApp.java:212)
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644):    at com.bluetooth.activities.AccelerometerControl.onSensorChanged(AccelerometerControl.java:170)
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644):    at android.hardware.SensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SensorManager.java:580)
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-16 21:33:39.471: E/AndroidRuntime(13644):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I cannot understand what goes wrong, the NullPointerException is cool and all but doesn't help me much. Line 212 is the `r.write(out);` line.

## Edit

The problem was that inside the `ConnectThread` the `mmSocket.connect();` didn't go any further (it's a blocking function). My connection wasn't made, but also did not fail, and thus the `mConnectedThread` was never created. When trying to write to a `null` object I got a NullPointerException.

The only solution I can think of to this new problem is to make a timeout thread and then some kind of a "handshake" so that my phone recognizes my device as a legitimate robot in case the user selects a wrong device.

Comment: mConnectedThread is null. Have you initialized it? check for null before assigning

Comment: Thanks, that was it, now to find why isn't it initialized...

Comment: you havent posted the relevant code